# Computing averages in a vector in Matlab

Tags: vector, binary, average, matlab

I have a vector `A` in Matlab of dimension `(m*2^n)x1` composed by zeros or ones. I want to obtain a vector `B` of the same dimension as `A` in which each non-zero element is the average among the non-zero elements in the subgroup of `2^(n-1)` elements of `A` it belongs to. To be more precise, suppose `m=6`,`n=2` so that `2^n=4` and A can be divided in `6` subgroups of `4` elements

```
A=[0;0;1;1; 1;1;1;1; 0;1;0;1; 0;0;0;0; 1;1;0;0; 1;0;0;0]
```

Hence

```
B=[0;0;1/2;1/2; 1/4;1/4;1/4;1/4; 0;1/2;0;1/2; 0;0;0;0; 1/2;1/2;0;0; 1;0;0;0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
n = 2;

t1 = reshape(A,2^n,[])
t2 = sum(t1)

B = reshape(bsxfun(@rdivide,t1,t2),[],1)
B(isnan(B))=0
```